# Processing XML elements inline with text

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a program which reads an XML file using Java DOM and processes certain element. For example, here is part of the document I am looking at:

```
<Flow>
        <Id>306</Id>
        <Type>Simple</Type>
        <FlowContent Width="0.2000000000000000111">
          <P Id="523"><T xml:space="preserve" Id="652">A spouse’s pension would be paid equal to&#x20;<O Id="351"/>% of your Core pension at date of death.</T>
          </P>
        </FlowContent>
```

(Note: this is exported from a program called GMC Inspire Designer, so I have no control over its format.)

I can process most elements fine, but have issues with text content which also contains elements. In the example above, another layout object `<O Id="351"/>` (referencing another piece of text or a variable) occurs in the body of the text.

I can look up this element and retrieve it using the ID number. This is the element linked in the above snippet:

```
<Variable>
    <Id>351</Id>
    <Name>CAMT44</Name>
```

What I would then like to do is output information from the linked node (e.g., I could look up the node with ID 351 and retrieve the name etc. then display this information in place of where the element appears within the string).

I currently look up children and store the ID in a string array like so:

```
NodeList nl = e.getElementsByTagName("O");
sa = new String[nl.getLength()]; // Set up new array to hold child ids

for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    sa[i] = nodeToElement(nl.item(i)).getAttribute("Id");
}
```

I'm very much a Java beginner, so I've been wondering if DOM was the correct choice for this project. Perhaps I should have used SAX instead, but as I don't have much XML experience, I'm not sure which best suits my needs and, as I mentioned, I have managed to do most of the things I need, it's just this last tricky bit that I'm stuck on.

Currently my output looks like this:

> IF CR.SCHEME == "EXCT" PRINT:
>
> "A spouse’s pension would be paid equal to % of your Core pension at
>   date of death, ignoring the fact that you may have chosen to convert
>   part of your pension into a lump sum at retirement."
>
> Child flow: 351

It would be great if there is some way to do this using DOM. Apologies if anything is unclear, I'm new to most of this.

Comment: It's not obvious what you want to achieve. Should `<O Id="351">` be replaced by some other piece of text that is identified by "351"?

Comment: Hi forty-two, yes that is what I'm trying to achieve. I will update the question with this info.

Comment: ¿You have two Elements with the same "id" in the document ?   <p id="351>content to set  in O element</p>  and <O id="351" > ?

Comment: Hi, I am architect of GMC Inspire Designer and exported ids are unique only if there is just one Layout module, which is actually defined by XML Element named Layout not shown in question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
    String output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Node n = nl.item(i);
        if(n.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            output += n.getTextContent();
        } else if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && n.getNodeName().equals("O")) {
            output += lookup(doc, ((Element)n).getAttribute("id"));

        }
    }
    System.out.println(output);
```

The lookup method is something you would need to implement yourself but it would look something like this:

```
private static String lookup(Document doc, String id) {
    return "<IMPLEMENT_LOOKUP_HERE>";
}
```